# Update geojson shapes' colors with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

Following this tutorial:

http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html

I created a map using this piece of code:

```
function loadNeighborhoods()
{
    $.ajax({async: false, dataType: "json", url: "https://nycdatastables.s3.amazonaws.com/2013-08-19T18:22:23.125Z/community-districts-polygon.geojson", success: function(data)
    {
        // Add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
        geojson = L.geoJson(data,  
        {
            style: style,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }).addTo(map);
    }});

    // Control that shows state info on hover
    info = L.control();

    info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
        this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    info.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = (props ? '<b> Region ID:'+ props.id +' </b><br />' : 'Hover over a state');
        if (props && !_.isEmpty(noiseMapMatrix))
            pieChart(noiseMapMatrix, props.id);
    };

    info.addTo(map);
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) 
{
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}

// Defines the style of the neighborhoods' polygons
function style(feature) 
{
    return {
        fillColor: '#FFEDA0',
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

function getColor(regionId) 
{
    var count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < complaints_type; j++)
    {   
        for (k = 0; k < time_slots; k++)
        {
            count += noiseMatrix[regionId][j][k];
        }
    }
    return count > 1000 ? '#800026' :
           count > 500  ? '#BD0026' :
           count > 200  ? '#E31A1C' :
           count > 100  ? '#FC4E2A' :
           count > 50   ? '#FD8D3C' :
           count > 20   ? '#FEB24C' :
           count > 10   ? '#FED976' :
                          '#FFEDA0';
}
```

However, the matrix `noiseMatrix`, that is going to be used to define the color of each community district (geojson polygon) is just filled when the users opens a file in the browser. So, at the beginning, the polygons have the same color. I'm wondering how to update these colors when the user selects the properly file, i.e., how and where to call the function `style` (?) again.

I'm trying something like this:

```
function fillStyle()
{
    geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {    
        layer.setStyle({fillColor : getComplaintsCountColor(layer.feature.id, true)}) 
    });
    // Legend of the states' color
    var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) 
    {
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200],
            labels = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            div.innerHTML +=
                '<div style="background:' + getComplaintsCountColor(grades[i] + 1, false) + '; border-radius: 50%; width: 10px; height: 10px; display:inline-block;"></div> ' +
                grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+');
        }

    return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);
```

}

But the following function is reseting the style to the initial one:

```
function resetHighlight(e) 
{
    var layer = e.target;

    geojson.resetStyle(layer);
    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) 
    {
        layer.bringToBack();
    }
//  d3.selectAll(".piechart").style("opacity", 0);
    info.update();
}

function highlightFeature(e) 
{
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 3,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) 
    {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
    info.update(layer.feature);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use

```
geojson.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.attributes.id),
        color: 'white'
    }
})
```

Call it after `noiseMatrix` is initialized.

Otherwise, you can remove the layer and create it again with the new style.

```
map.removeLayer(geojson);
```

This way you avoid changing how `resetHighlight` works.